# Why are there conditions for the chain rule of limits?

Tags: limits

I'm reading about the chain rule for limits written on Wiki :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Chain_rule

My question is: How do those conditions come from ? I read a proof of this based on transitivity here:
https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/chain-rule-for-limits.82533/ 
but can't find/comprehend the restrictions imposed by the proof.

Comment: Wikipedia gives you a reason why in the form of a counterexample.

Comment: That's right. But my actual question is how do they deduce that ? What makes sure this rule will work if these restrictions are satisfied ?

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious in the case of continuity at the points in question.

I will consider metric spaces $(X_1,d_1), (X_2,d_2), (X_3,d_3)$ and maps $f_1:X_1 \to X_2, f_2: X_2 \to X_3. $

Let $ \lim_{y \to b}f_2(y)= c, \lim_{x \to a}f_1(x)= b.$

Suppose there is a $ \delta > 0$ for which $d_2(g(x),b) > 0$ if $ 0 < d_1(x,a) < \delta.$

We know $\forall \epsilon' > 0 \exists \delta > 0 $ for which $ 0 <d_1(x,a) < \delta \implies  0 < d_2(f_1(x),b) < \epsilon'$ This just the definition of convergence, with the extra condition in the prior paragraph.

We know $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \epsilon' > 0 $ for which $ 0 <d_2(y,b) < \epsilon' \implies  d_3(f_2(y),c) < \epsilon.$ This just the definition of convergence of a function to a limit.

So we use the transitivity of implication $(\implies)$, and set $y := f_1(x)$ to write the following:

So we know $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \epsilon' > 0 $ for which $ 0 <d_1(x,b) < \epsilon' \implies  d_3(f_2 ( f_1 (x),c) < \epsilon$.

I hope this helps.